in JSP page javascript code is not initiating
I am trying to achieve 2 set registration page with next and back buttons. when im clicking next the javascript code is not working. if i'm using  it is hitting the servlet.
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#div1");
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("#div2");
    x.style.display = "block!important";
    y.style.display = "none!important";
    
    alert("outside");
    
function myFunction() {
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "block";
        }   
    alert("inside 1");
    }
    
function myFunctionTwo() {
    if (y.style.display === "block") {
        y.style.display = "none";
        x.style.display = "block";
        }
    alert("inside 2");
    }

}); 



</script>

 <form action="UserDetailsController" method="GET">
            <div class="col-8" id="div1" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 50px;">
                <div class="row" style="background: #fff; padding: 25px; border-radius: 20px;">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="./img/logo.jpg" width="140" alt="">
                        <h4>It's time to join the Mahasri Infotech community!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstname" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="cnfpassword" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cnfpassword" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="country" class="form-label">Country of Residence</label>
                        <select  multiple class="form-select mutli-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example" name="country">
                            <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
                            <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="3">Albania</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="city" class="form-label">City of Residence</label>
                        <select class="form-select mutli-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example" name="city" multiple="multiple">
                            <option selected>-Select-</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-3">
                            <!-- <button class="btn btn-cstm text-white" onclick="togglework()"></button> -->
                            <!-- <input type="button" class="btn btn-cstm text-white" id="toggleButton" value="Next" /> -->
                            <a class="btn btn-cstm text-white" id="toggleButton" onclick="myFunction()">Next</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
            </div>
            <div class="col-8" id="div2" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 50px;">
                <div class="row" style="background: #fff; padding: 25px; border-radius: 20px;">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="./logo.jpg" width="140" alt="">
                        <h4>It's time to join the Mahasri Infotech community!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lang" class="form-label">Native Language(s) (max. 3)</label>
                        <select class="form-select mutli-dropdown" name="lang" multiple>
                            <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
                            <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="3">Albania</option><option value="4">Algeria</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="ref" class="form-label">How did you hear about us? (Optional)</label>
                        <select class="form-select mutli-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example" name="ref" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
                            <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="3">Albania</option><option value="4">Algeria</option><option value="5">American Samoa</option><option value="6">Andorra</option><option value="7">Angola</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="expert" class="form-label">I am an expert in (max. 5)</label>
                        <select class="form-select mutli-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example" name="expert" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
                            <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="3">Albania</option><option value="4">Algeria</option><option value="5">American Samoa</option><option value="6">Andorra</option><option value="7">Angola</option><option value="8">Anguilla</option><option value="9">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="opportunities" class="form-label">I am interested in opportunities in (max. 10)</label>
                        <select class="form-select mutli-dropdown" aria-label="Default select example" name="opportunities" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
                            <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="3">Albania</option><option value="4">Algeria</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="upload" class="form-label">Upload resume/CV (Optional)</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" accept=".docx,.doc,.rtf,.txt,.pdf" id="upload" name="upload">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div style="height: 30px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="terms" type="checkbox" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> for using the OneForma pages.. *
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="nonDisclosure" type="checkbox" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                I have read, SIGNED, and agree to the <a href="#">Non-Disclosure Agreement(NDA)</a> for using the OneForma pages.. *
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="privacy" type="checkbox" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>, the <a href="#">GDPR CLAUSE</a> the <a href="#">COOKIES POLICY</a> for using the OneForma pages.. *
                            </label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-3">
                           <!--  <button class="btn btn-secondary text-white mr5"  onclick="togglework()">Back</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-cstm text-white">Next</button> -->
                            
                            <!-- <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-white mr5" id="toggleButton2" value="Back" /> -->
                            <a class="btn btn-cstm text-white" id="toggleButton2" onclick="myFunctionTwo()">back</a>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-cstm text-white" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   </form>

i was expecting when clicking on next the second div style property should be block and first div goes to hide.
I have tried putting two function individually, tried putting alert to see if it is passing through. still nothing

Do the alerts show?

There's far too much "noise" in the code you have provided. Please provided a minimal example which shows the problem

.querySelectorAll() returns a list of nodes. You cannot directly access .style on the list; you have to iterate through the list to affect each node in the list individually.

Where is the connection to java and jsp?

first of all $(document).ready  is a jQuery code so you should add this library to your code ,
and second    document.querySelectorAll("#div1"); when you want to select one element is not good choice and selecting  with ID   shows that you just want a div with id of div1 so use document.querySelector("#div1"); or document.getElementById('div1') (better)
and the last thing is you declared two functions but never call them correctly
if you don't want to add jQuery  in your code instead of $(document).ready
use window.addEventListener('load', function())

"and the last thing is you declare tow functions but never call them" - They do. OP has onclick="myFunction()" and onclick="myFunctionTwo()" in their HTML. (Although this wont work because the functions are not part of the global object.)
